# How to make a picklist based on other object record values

Tags: picklist, record

I have add records in "Products" object. Now i want to create a picklist based on "product name" in another object.

Comment: It sounds like you want to make a look-up field instead of a picklist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can easily do this

Controller

```
public String selectedVal{get;set;} 

public list<selectOption> getProductnames()
{
  list<selectOption> soList = new list<selectOption>();
  for(Product prod : [Select Id, Name from Product LIMIT 1000])
        soList .add(new selectOption(prod.id, Prod.Name));
  return soList;
}
```

Then in VF page

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedVal}" size="1"> 
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Productnames}" /> 
</apex:selectList>
```

Remember that using this approach you can only display 1000 records and if you want to add none as Option then you need to change limit to 999.

Comment: It works fine. As Account and contact have look-up relationship, I need to get all the accounts names as a picklist in contact